# ant copy tag won't keep file kind

Tags: ant, tags, copy

I'm trying to build a Mac OS X bundle application automatically.
When copying the file "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub" of kind "Unix Executable File" with the copy tag:
`<copy file="${stub.file}" todir="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.app/Contents/MacOS"/>` and getting a file of kind "Document" and the bundle doesn't execute. If I copy it from Finder it works fine.

Is there a way to copy it and keep it's kind with ant?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file ist copied correctly, but the execute permission ist lost as described in the [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html):

> **Unix Note:** File permissions are not retained when files are copied; they end up with the default UMASK permissions instead. This
>   is caused by the lack of any means to query or set file permissions in
>   the current Java runtimes.

You have to use the `cp` command or change the permission later with `chmod`:

```
<apply executable="chmod">
  <arg value="a+rx"/>
  <file file="${stub.file}" basedir="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.app/Contents/MacOS"/>
</apply>
```